# Short story: Cop chasing serial killer, both are shape shifting aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, shape-shifter

I'm looking for the title of a short story I read years ago.

It is about a cop chasing down a serial killer but it turns out both of them are actually aliens and the cop turns into a blob and envelopes the other alien until it dies.

It was part of an anthology.  I read it maybe 7 years ago but the anthology could have been much older than that.  For some reason I keep thinking it was in a horror anthology as opposed to to a straight up sci-fi anthology.  The story takes place on Earth and it reads like a standard cop/detective story but then you get to the end and boom you get the alien twist.

Comment: Hi there! Could you please [edit] in some more elements about this story? For instance, how long ago is "years ago"? 5 years? 20? 50? Was that story written in English, was it a translation? Did you read it in an anthology - if so, what did the cover look like? Stuff like that, and whatever else you can think of, to increase the chances of a successful identification. Cheers!

Comment: That does sound like Larry Niven's The Meddler (for which I can't find a short link giving the description, but can find a couple of illegal sites with the full text....)

Comment: @user14111 - it is not. It's also not one that came up when I was searching...

Comment: In The Meddler the private eye isn't an alien IIRC.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - you're quite right; but he is followed around by an alien, and it's possible that a vaguely remembered story might also confuse something like that

Comment: I, too, thought of "The Meddler" when I read the title, but then ending doesn't match.

Answer (score 8):

Dean Koontz, "*Hardshell*".

It's in these anthologies: "*Predators*" (1993),  ["*Strange Highways*"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32445.Strange_Highways) (1991), and "*Night Vision 4*" (1987). Two reviews on Goodreads for the *Strange Highways* short story mention it's about a cop and a serial killer chasing each other and that they obviously aren't quote fully human. The killer is also mentioned to be a shape shifter.

> **Dead men don’t bleed.**
>
> A game of cat and mouse develops in an abandoned warehouse (have you notice that in any story the warehouse always are abandoned?!) between a wounded cop and a vicious killer.
>
> However, who is the “cat” and who is the “mouse” is still to be seen, since there are a lot beyond the evident.
>
> <sub>[Strange Highways review, Alejandro](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1016775189?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1)</sub>

> Hardshell - In a abandoned warehouse, LAPD Det. Snow is chased by immortal Karl Skagg the "Shape Changer". He learns Karl's 300+ years old. And Det. Snow could to be made immortal?
>
> <sub>[Strange Highways review, Fred](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1220023412?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1)</sub>

Comment: Thank you  for your help!  It is Hardshell by Dean Koontz.  I would never have been able to remember this on my own :)

Comment: One day we'll come to you with a question.... ;-)